# Playing .avi in linux

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, matlab-guide, avi

I have written a code to save two movies in Matlab. The problem is that, the movie "graphh.avi" is consist of first movie("chert") also. I want it to show just graphs and not the first saved movie("chert.avi").
Could anyone help? Any answer is highly appreciated.

```
clear all
close all
cla
h = plot(x, y, '.g', 'MarkerSize', 10);
set(gca,'Color',[0 0 0]);
 set(gcf,'doublebuffer','on')
set(gca,'YTick',[]);
set(gca,'XTick',[]);
plot(x,y,'.g','markersize',10)
drawnow
currFrame = getframe;
writeVideo(vidObj,currFrame);
h = plot(x, y, '.g', 'MarkerSize', 10);
drawnow

hist(blocksize)
currFrame = getframe;
writeVideo(vid,currFrame);
end
close(vidObj);
close(vid)
```

The code after doing the first answer becomes as below. The problem solved but there is another problem now: black movie with green points became so messy.

```
clear all
close all
l = 20;
r = 3;
v = 0.5;
dt = 1;
nn=200;
figure(h1); % set figure 1 as current figure
h = plot(x, y, '.g', 'MarkerSize', 10);
set(gca,'Color',[0 0 0]);
set(gcf,'doublebuffer','on')
set(gca,'YTick',[]);
set(gca,'XTick',[]);
plot(x,y,'.g','markersize',10)
drawnow
currFrame = getframe(h1); % gets only figure 1
writeVideo(vidObj,currFrame);
 h = plot(x, y, '.g', 'MarkerSize', 10);
drawnow
figure(h2); % set figure 2 as current figure
hist(blocksize)
currFrame = getframe(h2); % gets only figure 2
writeVideo(vid,currFrame);
end
close(vidObj);
close(vid);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use figures handles when calling `getframe`. See how I modified your code:

```
% some code...
vvy = v.*sin(tetha);
h1 = figure('Color',[0 0 0])
axis([0 l 0 l])
% some more code...
h2 = figure
hold on
vid = VideoWriter('graphh.avi');
% and more code...
% for loop
    figure(h1); % set figure 1 as current figure
    % plot whatever on this figure
    currFrame = getframe(h1); % gets only figure 1
    writeVideo(vidObj,currFrame);
    % blah blah...
    figure(h2); % set figure 2 as current figure
    % plot whatever on this figure
    currFrame = getframe(h2); % gets only figure 2
    writeVideo(vid,currFrame);
% end of loop
```

**EDIT:**

in your modified code you're calling `h = plot(x, y, '.g', 'MarkerSize', 10);` three times in a row for no reason, so get rid of it. the problem you encountered stems from plotting another set of point *in addition* to the previous one, so the axes get filled with points. One solution for that is to use `set(h,'XData',x,'YData',y)` like so:

```
figure(h1); % set figure 1 as current figure
set(gca,'Color',[0 0 0]);
set(gcf,'doublebuffer','on')
set(gca,'YTick',[]);
set(gca,'XTick',[]);
if exist('h','var') && ishandle(h) % if handle exists just change coordinates
    set(h,'XData',x,'YData',y)
else  % only for the first time you plot that
    h = plot(x, y, '.g', 'MarkerSize', 10);
end
drawnow
currFrame = getframe(h1); % gets only figure 1
writeVideo(vidObj,currFrame);
```

Comment: I edited the code in the question as your answer. The problem solved but there is another problem now: black movie with green points became so messy

Comment: please compare the black movie in the first code and second one(modified by your answer)